# Can I migrate a model to a datasource via the commandline slc tool?

Tags: orm, loopbackjs, strongloop

I can migrate a model via the composer of the arc tool, and I could write a small node.js script in my app to auto-migrate the model to my MySQL database, configured as a datasource, but I would really love to simply type something from the slc commandline, as part of my create process from command line to migrate my model. For example:

```
slc loopback:migrate --datasources=server/datasources.json --model-config=server/model-config.json --datasource=mymysqldb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a script in ***/server/bin/automigrate.js***

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../server'));


    var models = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../model-config.json'));
    var datasources = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../datasources.json'));

    function autoMigrateAll(){
        Object.keys(models).forEach(function(key) {
            if (typeof models[key].dataSource != 'undefined') {
                if (typeof datasources[models[key].dataSource] != 'undefined') {
                    app.dataSources[models[key].dataSource].automigrate(key, function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log('Model ' + key + ' migrated');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    autoMigrateAll();
```

And run by using command

***cd toYourProjectFolder***

***node server/bin/automigrate.js***

Make sure you have your **datasource.json** is configure with MySQL
and applied to model-config.json

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that from the slc loopback command line tool as of yet. Please feel free to submit a feature request at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues.

At the moment, you would have to create a simple script that calls the `automigrate` command as you've already been doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple type of databases (connectors) so I made this script which works for me:

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../server'));

var dataSources = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../datasources.json'));

autoUpdateAll();

// ------------------------------------

function autoUpdateAll(){
    Object.keys(dataSources).forEach(function(dataSourceName) {
        var dataSourceObj = app.dataSources[dataSourceName];
        if(!dataSourceObj) return;
        dataSourceObj.autoupdate(function(err, result) {
            if(err) return console.error(err);
            console.log('Datasource ' + dataSourceName + ' update (autoupdate();)');
        });
    });
}
```